# Proof of Green's Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am looking at the proof of the Green theorem.

To show that $$\oint _S (Mdx+Ndy)= \iint_R \left( \frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} \right) dxdy$$we do the following:

To show that $\oint _S Mdx=-\iint_R \frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}}dxdy$,we consider this graph:

[image]

And to show that $\oint _S Ndy=\iint_R \frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{x}}dxdy$,we consider this graph:

[image]

Why do we choose these graphs at each case?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question this time. And this is probably an off-topic comment but much of what elementary calculus books say about these graphs it not so important and does not lead to the most general proof. It is best to prove the theorem first for a rectangle and then to do it for an arbitrary domain by approximation.

Comment: I've changed the title to something more expressive, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Line integral is independent of parametrization :

If $f = (P,Q)$ is a vector field, then assume that a curve $C$, a boundary of $R$, has a parametrization $r(t)=(x,y)(t),\ 0\leq t\leq l$. Then for a line integral $
\int_C f\cdot dr $ we have to consider $\ast=\int_0^l P(x(t),y(t)) x'(t) dt$

Here $s(u)=r(t(u)),\ t(a)=0,\ t(b)=l$ is a re-parametrization so that $$ 
\ast =\int_a^b P(x(t(u)),y(t(u)) ) x'(t(u)) t'(u) du =
\int_a^b P(s(u)) \frac{d}{dt} x( t(u)) du $$

Hence $\ast$ is independent of parametrization

(2) Proof of Green theorem :

For $\ast$, we use the following specific parametrization $c_1(t)=(t,f_1(t)),\ a\leq x\leq b$ and $c_2(t) 
=(b-t,f_2(b-t)),\ 0\leq t\leq b-a$ for $S$ (cf. first figure in OP)

\begin{align*}&\int_{c_1\cup c_2} P(x,y)dx \\&= 
\int_a^b P(t,f_1(t)) dt + \int_0^{b-a} P(b-t,f_2(b-t)) \frac{d}{dt} (b-t) dt
\\&= \int_a^b P(t,f_1(t)) dt + \int_b^{a} P(u,f_2(u)) du 
\\&=\int_a^b \bigg\{P(t,f_1(t)) - P(t,f_2(t)) \bigg\} dt 
\\&=\int_a^b \int_{f_1(t)}^{f_2(t)} -P_y(t,y) dydt
\\&= \int\int_R -P_y dA
\end{align*}

And for $\int_C Q(x,y)dy$, if we use $c_1,\ c_2$, we can not calculate easily as far as I know. So we use another parametrization $c_1=(g_2(y),y),\ d\leq y\leq c$ and $c_2(t)=(g_1(c-t),c-t),\ 0\leq t\leq c-d$.